# grails 5 recompile ends in StackOverflow Exception

Tags: grails

I'm actually updating an old grails 2.4.2 project to grails 5.2.2. My IDE is IntelliJ Idea (but the problem exists, even if I start grails from the command line through *run-app*)

Using adoptOpenJDK 11.0.16.1+1

Every time I've changed e.g. a controller, the recompile process is started and ends in an stackOverflow Exception:

```
File /.../grails-app/controllers/xyz/SyParameterController.groovy changed, recompiling...
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:73)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
    at grails.util.Environment.setCurrentReloadError(Environment.groovy:238)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor777.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2839)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3854)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:496)
```

I already enhanced the Java-Stack-Size in the build.gradle file.

Is this a known error or do I have an obvious mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was a known problem that was fixed in 5.2.3: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12608

EDIT: if you can't upgrade to 5.2.3, you can add grails.util.Environment locally and override the offending method as such:

```
static void setCurrentReloadError(Throwable currentReloadError) {
    Environment.@currentReloadError = currentReloadError
}
```

This would not be a recommended long-term solution, but may be easier than upgrading, just to confirm that's your issue.